# How do you solve: $y'=c_1e^{-\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve that ODE? I understand it has gamma functions but I have no clue where to start. Thanks
$$y'=c_1e^{-\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: Hint: Integrate both sides. Somewhat nasty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amzoti commented, just write $$y=c_1 \int e^{-\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$ Life could be easier if you change variable and do $$\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}=z$$ $$x=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2/3} z^{2/3}$$ $$dx=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}dz$$ which then leads to $$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}c_1\int \frac{ e^{-z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}dz$$

Since you mention gamma function, I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score -1):

You can start by finding that $$\begin{array}{rrcl} & c_{1}\cdot \mathsf{e}^{-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\sqrt{x^{3}}} & = & y^{\prime} \\ & & = & \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \\ \Rightarrow & \mathrm{d}y & = & c_{1}\cdot\mathsf{e}^{-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\sqrt{x^{3}}}\,\mathrm{d}x \\ \Rightarrow & y & = & \int c_{1}\cdot\mathsf{e}^{-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\sqrt{x^{3}}}\,\mathrm{d}x \end{array}$$